# libraries must use the exact same version specification (mixing versions can lead to runtime crashes). Found versions 28.0.0-alpha1, 26.1.0

Tags: android, firebase, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

ll com.android.support libraries must use the exact same version

> specification (mixing versions can lead to runtime crashes). Found
>   versions 28.0.0-alpha1, 26.1.0. Examples include
>   com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:28.0.0-alpha1 and
>   com.android.support:customtabs:26.1.0 less... (Ctrl+F1)  There are
>   some combinations of libraries, or tools and libraries, that are
>   incompatible, or can lead to bugs. One such incompatibility is
>   compiling with a version of the Android support libraries that is not
>   the latest version (or in particular, a version lower than your
>   targetSdkVersion).

my gradle dependencies:-

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:15.0.1'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.1'
```

warning on this dependencies -----------------------------

> ```
> implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0-alpha1'
> ```

```
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision:15.0.2'
implementation 'com.theartofdev.edmodo:android-image-cropper:2.3.+'
implementation 'com.memetix:microsoft-translator-java-api:0.6.2'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crash:16.0.1'
implementation 'com.facebook.android:audience-network-sdk:4.+'
```

[image]

[image]>

Comment: Check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42374426/2196176).

Comment: you are using different versions of firebase, which is bad itself. Each of them use it's ovn version of support libraries, which is causing this message

Comment: what is compileSdkVersion ?

Comment: compileSdkVersion is 28

Comment: i m using latest version of firebase  @VladyslavMatviienko

Comment: yes, but still it is 2 different versions. YOu may try to use the lower one for both (15.0.x)

Comment: i get this error when set lower version Failed to notify dependency resolution listener.
The library com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-base is being requested by various other libraries at [[15.0.2,15.0.2], [16.0.0,16.0.0]], but resolves to 16.0.0. Disable the plugin and check your dependencies tree using ./gradlew :app:dependencies.

Comment: change compileSdkVersion 27 and com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1

Comment: sorry i want solution with latest compileSdkVersion "28"

Answer (score 6):

Something's using older library and The culprit is firebase-core:16~;

After quite some trials I resolved this issue.

From [this answere](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42374426/2196176) and  [this answer](http://sainuo.org/index.php?q=oKipp7eAc2SktaTSttjm1anLrdKpgdLkuZ_HnYGApaZwdI2Q) I solved the error.

> You need to manually add dependencies that are conflicting. (To find conflicting dependencies an easy way is to hover over highlighted errors.)
>   You can either downgrade your appcompat library to the given/hinted one which is not recommended or manually declare those dependicies.

I Used this code with all updated libraries today and solved errors:

```
dependencies {
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0-rc01'

implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.2'

//this thing is carusing error, to solve - see hints and manually add them.

implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.1'

implementation 'com.android.support:support-media-compat:28.0.0-rc01'

implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0-rc01'


//implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.2.0'
/*implementation ("com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.1"){
    exclude group: 'com.android.support'
}
*/

testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
}
```

Such behavior makes new developers head scratch.

If this solves your problem please let others know too.
Happy coding.

**Update**.

Note: Don't forget to check if there's other libraries added to your project causing warning.

Proof of its working.
[image]

Comment: chcek other stuff. like firabase ads. say what warning you got after using this method. Add them too and it will work.

Comment: @JayminBhadani maybe you are not testing it correctly. As it has latest rc-01 version and yours alpha-1.

Comment: same problem with rc-01..! this problem with freebase lib version if i remove freebase lib it working but i need it thanks.!

Answer (score 1):

**Use this dependencie**

`implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'`

Comment: getting this warring when use this dependencies "All com.android.support libraries must use the exact same version specification (mixing versions can lead to runtime crashes). Found versions 27.1.1, 26.1.0. Examples include com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:27.1.1 and com.android.support:customtabs:26.1."

Answer (score 1):

This is caused because your image cropper library contains older version of support library. Use this on your Image Cropper library:

```
implementation ("com.theartofdev.edmodo:android-image-cropper:2.3.+"){
    exclude group: 'com.android.support'
}
```

This will remove your gradle issue .

Comment: Then add same thing to Facebook and Translator library one by one until you get rid of error.

Comment: Try with Translator also. I am sure Image cropper uses older version because I use it.

Comment: where is Translator  please describe it.?

Comment: add same to microsoft-translator-java-api library

Answer (score 1):

Use this dependencies below

```
implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0'
```

Answer (score 1):

```
implementation ("com.theartofdev.edmodo:android-image-cropper:2.3.+"){
    exclude group: 'com.android.support'
}
```

nitinkumarp gives working advice. Perhaps the conflict has several dependencies. You need to check each one, remove all dependencies and add and synchronize one by one until a warning appears. This will be the dependency that causes the warning.

Comment: This appears to be a comment on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51949439/1364007) by [nitinkumarp](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5260051/nitinkumarp) that has been posted as a separate answer.